# pandas How to find the group with the maximum value and delete the group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this：

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dataA = [["2005-1-20", "9:35", 5], ["2005-1-20", "9:40", 8], ["2005-1-20", "9:45", 7],
   ["2005-1-20","9:50", 4], ["2005-1-20", "10:00", 2],
   ["2005-1-21", "9:35", 2], ["2005-1-21", "9:40", 3], ["2005-1-21", "9:45", 4],
   ["2005-1-21","9:50", 4], ["2005-1-21", "10:00", 775],
   ["2005-1-22", "9:35", 12], ["2005-1-22", "9:40", 13], ["2005-1-22", "9:45", 14],
   ["2005-1-22","9:50", 14], ["2005-1-22", "10:00", 15]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = dataA, columns=["date", "min", "val"])
```

```
print（df）
     date      min    val
0   2005-1-20   9:35    5
1   2005-1-20   9:40    8
2   2005-1-20   9:45    7
3   2005-1-20   9:50    4
4   2005-1-20   10:00   2
5   2005-1-21   9:35    2
6   2005-1-21   9:40    3
7   2005-1-21   9:45    4
8   2005-1-21   9:50    4
9   2005-1-21   10:00   775
10  2005-1-22   9:35    12
11  2005-1-22   9:40    13
12  2005-1-22   9:45    14
13  2005-1-22   9:50    14
14  2005-1-22   10:00   15
```

i want to find the group with the maximum value where min=10:00, and delete the group groupby date,
how to it?

Comment: Please post expected output.

Comment: Søren Grove Vejlstrup give the correct answer，  thank you too !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution, it only removes one, even if two dates have the highest value.

```
#Filter, so that you only have the values you want to compare
only_data_at_ten = df[ df.minute == '10:00']

#Find the highest value by sorting ascending and getting the last value
date_to_remove = only_data_at_ten.sort_values('val').date.iloc[-1]

#Filter your data so that you have only the dates, that are NOT the one you found
cleaned_data = df[ df.date != date_to_remove]
```

Comment: only_data_at_ten = df[ df.minute == '10:00']  has an error,   change to   only_data_at_ten = df[ df['min']== '10:00']  ,  it works !    and  your answer is what i need  ,thank you very much !

Comment: one more question， what if i want to delete two max value ？

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) with set `min` column to index for get `min` values by maximal in `val` per groups:

```
s = df.set_index('min').groupby('date')['val'].idxmax()
print (s)
date
2005-1-20     9:40
2005-1-21    10:00
2005-1-22    10:00
Name: val, dtype: object
```

And then test dates matched `10:00` filtered in `s.index` in [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for get this groups in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['date'].isin(s.index[s.ne('10:00')])]
print (df)
        date    min  val
0  2005-1-20   9:35    5
1  2005-1-20   9:40    8
2  2005-1-20   9:45    7
3  2005-1-20   9:50    4
4  2005-1-20  10:00    2
```

Or use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and then filter `dates`:

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['date', 'val']).drop_duplicates('date', keep='last')

dates = df1.loc[df1['min'].ne('10:00'), 'date']
print (dates)
1    2005-1-20
Name: date, dtype: objec

df = df[df['date'].isin(dates)]
print (df)
        date    min  val
0  2005-1-20   9:35    5
1  2005-1-20   9:40    8
2  2005-1-20   9:45    7
3  2005-1-20   9:50    4
4  2005-1-20  10:00    2
```

Comment: this answer get what i  want to delete,  but,  thank you too !

Comment: @61938388 - So need change `ne` to `eq` only for select for `equal` instead `notequal`

Answer (score 0):

```
s=(df.sort_values(by=['date','min'])['min']=='10:00').cumsum()

df[df['date'].str.contains((df.groupby([s,'date'])['val'].max().reset_index(level=0))['val'].idxmax())].drop(columns=['date'])


     min  val
5   9:35    2
6   9:40    3
7   9:45    4
8   9:50    4
9  10:00  775
```